# Do Particle Accelerators Generate External Electrical or Magnetic Interference?

Tags: electromagnetism, estimation, biology, particle-accelerators

Among others, I am engaged in private pendulum research work during which there have been reports of disturbances of unknown pseudo-periodic human origin.  It has been surmised that transmitted noise from particle accelerators may be the cause. My primary questions are "Do particle accelerators cause nearby electrical and/or magnetic interference/noise, and what amplitudes could be expected".

Comment: *It has been surmised...* By whom, where?

Comment: "Disturbances of unknown pseudo-periodic human origin" = people driving trucks past your lab, or even people walking about inside the building, if it has flexible floors?

Answer (score 2):

Because particle accelerators produce lethal levels of radiation while operating, they are exceptionally well-shielded with metal, concrete, and earth.

Note also that the field strength for their magnets drops as 1/(distance)^3, making it unlikely that such could be detected at any significant distance away from the beam magnets.

In a previous lifetime, I worked in a high-tech research lab in Oregon when the Loma Prieta earthquake struck California, with its epicenter some 650 miles away from us. We routinely weighed samples to nanogram accuracy on a bank of Mettler microbalances each of which was mounted on a 500 pound block of concrete to isolate it from vibrations. One of these was taking data when the earthquake waves made it up to our building and shook it enough to destroy the experimental run, although none of us felt it.

(The timestamp on the raw data sheet allowed us to estimate the transit time of the shaking waves; alas, the margins of this page are too small for me to represent that here.)

As such, trucks, railroads, subways, etc. are a far more likely source of interference for you.

Comment: There are plenty of ion accelerators that have much lower radiation outputs (ion implant systems for semiconductor fab, say). Of course they also are much less likely to cause much interference to anything around them either. Even the 6MV-on-terminal HVE EN Tandem in my Ion Beam Lab rarely gets above a Controlled Area unless you are running protons.

Comment: Ah, those pesky protons. what can you say about them, anyway?

Comment: Well, really, He-3 was even better at making nuclear reactions than protons. Always good practice to check your ion/target combinations to not make a bunch of neutrons. Except, of course, when you wanted lots of neutrons (mainly D-D and D-T)...

Comment: The brother of one of my friends from HP is the current director of the Stanford accelerator lab complex (formerly SLAC). When next he comes up here for a visit, I will be ready with a good bottle of scotch- then we can talk protons, neutrons, klystrons, muons, morons, etc. Did you know that the main beamline at SLAC was decommissioned a few years ago? It has been sectioned up into several short segments with dedicated experiments installed in each. No more 10,000 foot e-beam...

Comment: Niels Nielson's answer two days ago was direct, helpful and informative and leads to further but more specific questions. Q1 - What is the maximum magnetic field strength at the external shielded surface of, for example, the Large Hadron Collider's beam magnets? Q2 - How often are the beam magnets switched ON? Q3 - For what period of time do they operate ? Q4 - Is the operation pulsed in any way?